# BadMethodCallException Method Illuminate\Translation\Translator::getFromJson does not exist

Tags: laravel-6, laravel-upgrade

```
BadMethodCallException
Method Illuminate\Translation\Translator::getFromJson does not exist.


Bad Method Call
Did you mean Illuminate\Translation\Translator::getLine() ?
```

> I have tried by given command but it's not working for me. same error
>   is showing.

```
php artisan view:clear
php artisan view:cache
```

also tried by these :

```
php artisan config:cache
php artisan config:clear
php artisan route:clear
```

> I have also deleted cache files from bootstrap/cache

** BUT till now It's Not Working :( **

Answer (score 3):

Laravel 6+ replaced `Translator` `getFromJson()` to just `get()`. If you find and replace all instances that should fix the issue.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I will try it In Sha ALLAH.

Comment: I found a file that uses `getFromJson()` .//App/Notification/PasswordReset.php.